# PowerShell: Positional Parameters and ValueFromPipeline

Tags: powershell

I have a toy problem that feels like it should be simple. I'd like to have a function like Join-Path that supports the pipe. Call it Build-Path. Thus, these statements (which are my tests 1-4) should be equivalent:

```
Get-Location | Build-Path Test

Get-Location | Build-Path -Right Test

Build-Path -Left (Get-Location) -Right Test

Build-Path (Get-Location) Test
```

I've tried a number of things, and the closest I can get these two functions (mutually exclusive):

A: Explicit position on both values; fails test 1

```
function Build-Path
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [String] $Left, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [String] $Right
)
{
    Join-Path $Left $Right
}
```

B: No position on the pipeline parameter, position of Right is 0; fails test 4

```
function Build-Path
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [String] $Left, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [String] $Right
)
{
    Join-Path $Left $Right
}
```

I've tried using ParameterSets in a number of ways (didn't save my attempts) with no success and I'm a bit stumped right now.

Thoughts?

Comment: `$left | Join-Path -ChildPath $right` <-- I'm pretty sure Join-Path does what you're asking already.

Comment: @RyanBemrose sounds pedantic, but not using positional parameters (ie. $left | Join-Path $right)

Comment: Separate issue:  You don't have a process block, which you really need when using pipeline input.  You're only using one object in the pipeline so it's not as obvious.

Comment: Easiest fix? swap your positions. Everything you have will work, the only thing you have to change is #4 where you have to swap parameter order.

Answer (score 5):

This can't work the way you want it to. Both of your arguments are the same data type, and PowerShell will use that to bind parameters before it looks at whether or not it came in on the pipeline, and it will try to fill positions starting at 0 right away.

I even tried redoing it with parameter sets:

```
function Build-Path {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Default',PositionalBinding=$false)]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='Default',
        Mandatory=$true, 
        ValueFromPipeline=$true
    )]
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='LooseyGoosey',
        Mandatory=$true,
        Position=0
    )]
    [String] 
    $Left, 

    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='Default',
        Mandatory=$true, 
        Position=0
    )]
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='LooseyGoosey',
        Mandatory=$true,
        Position=1
    )]
    [String] 
    $Right
)

    Join-Path $Left $Right
}
```

To see how PowerShell is binding parameters, use `Trace-Command`:

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression { Build-Path (Get-Location) Test } -Verbose -PSHost
```

You'll run into problems no matter how you slice it. No `DefaultParameterSet`? Parameter set cannot be resolved. Switch the defaults? Then you're just changing which invocation(s) work or don't.

You also can't make the `-Right` parameter a `[String[]]` array because during binding PowerShell will attempt to coerce, so a `[String]` will still be accepted and bound.

```
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Get-Location]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Get-Location]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Get-Location]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Build-Path]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Build-Path]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [C:\Users\Briantist] to parameter [Right]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: C:\Users\Briantist
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [C:\Users\Briantist] to param [Right] SKIPPED
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [C:\Users\Briantist] to parameter [Left]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: C:\Users\Briantist
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [C:\Users\Briantist] to param [Left] SKIPPED
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [C:\Users\Briantist] to parameter [Right]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: C:\Users\Briantist
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [C:\Users\Briantist] to param [Right] SKIPPED
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [C:\Users\Briantist] to parameter [Right]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: C:\Users\Briantist
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [C:\Users\Briantist] to param [Right] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Test] to parameter [Right]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: Test
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Test] to param [Right] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Build-Path]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PROMPTING for missing mandatory parameters using the host
```