How to parse mixed direct and piped function arguments in powershell?
I'm trying to handle the most obvious case of functions using mixed optional inputs. I would like the function to be able to process correctly the following command line options:
usage: 
  yolo 'BB' 'CC'
  'AA' | yolo 'CC'

As you might imagine, 'BB' could be an input filepath, and 'CC' a RegEx...
I have tried a lot, and can do either with pipe or without pipe (using args[]), but not both.
function yolo {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] [string] $AA,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position=1)] [string] $BB,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position=2)] [string] $CC
    )

    $n=$($args.count); $p=$($PsBoundParameters.Count)
    Write-Host "N: $n`nP: $p`n"
    Write-Host "`nAA: $AA`nBB: $BB`nCC: $CC`n"
    $PSBoundParameters.Keys
}

However, all the variables get jumbled up...
# Example-1
# yolo
N: 0
P: 0

AA:
BB:
CC:

# Example-2
# yolo "AA" "BB"
N: 0
P: 2

AA: AA
BB: BB
CC:

AA
BB

# Example-3
# "AA" | yolo "BB"

yolo: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command 
either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and 
its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

N: 0
P: 1

AA: BB
BB:
CC:

AA

Q: How can I ensure they end up in the right variable, regardless if passed from pipe or as arguments?
(a) Why doesn't the piped string end up in any of the parametered variable?
(b) How do I access it?
PS. Similarly named questions, where not of any help.

Instead of "AA" | yolo "BB", which uses positional parameters, try "AA" | yolo -bb "BB" which uses named parameters. Powershell binds values to the positional and named parameters before the pipeline - in your case the positional argument ”BB” is being bound to parameter -AA so by the time it comes to binding the pipeline values there’s no unassigned parameters left with the ValueFromPipeline attribute. In "AA" | yolo -bb "BB", ”BB” binds to parameter -bb so the pipeline value can still bind to -aa.

The similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015804/powershell-positional-parameters-and-valuefrompipeline - suggests using Trace-Command to see the binding logs with trace-command -name parameterbinding -expression { "aa" | yolo "bb" } -verbose -pshost

"'BB' could be an input filepath, and 'CC' a RegEx" - then what is AA?

Try [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline)] [string] $AA ? I.e. remove Position argument for parameter $AA (defaults to 0)…

@mclayton I'm afraid that the Trace-Command is not helpful here.

@MathiasR.Jessen In the exmaple above the "AA" would just be a longer string, or the output from cat -Raw ".\dummy.txt".

@JosefZ I don't quite understand the position argument TBH. Not very lucid explanation, since they're missing examples. Here ⏫ will be a great example to include in your MS documentation!

I've managed to partially work around this mess since, but it got more messy, using a combination of begin {} process {} end {} and wasting time with incomprehensible variables like $input (where values disappear when used, and thus also not able to copy), and added to $_ which also populates after each use of $input. Here we have grand example of the shortcomings of powershell. Taking 2 days, to do something trivial like passing and piping variables, which is trivially implemented in just about every other language I know.

@not2qubit I'm asking because it's entirely unclear what you're trying to do. Do you have a real life example instead?

Trace-Command is useful insomuch as it'll show you how PowerShell is actually resolving the example parameters, and that will show you why it's not working the way you want it to, but it won't help you change PowerShell's behaviour for sure. In short, if you want to use positional parameters and pipeline input you need to make sure your positional parameters don't bind to the ValueFromPipeline argument because there'll be nothing left to bind the pipeline argument to afterwards.
